# Matplotlib.plot Histogram has extra space

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm not sure how to word this; when I create my histogram it should have values from 0 to 255 [black to white values in shades of gray], but it almost always goes to around 300.  Is there something in my code which is messing around with the x-range?

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import urllib, cStringIO

file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen("http://www.animal-photos.org/_photo/2715313.jpg").read())
im = Image.open(file)
im = im.convert("L")
data = list(im.getdata())
plt.hist(data, color = "gray", bins = 256, label = "Gray Histogram", )
plt.xlabel("Gray Value (0,256)")
plt.show()
```

The first part [the file part] has been added just so that the code actually runs; the URL was just a black-and-white jpg that I had open.  The program cuts up the image and tells us via histogram how many pixels there are of varying grayness (given by a value 0 to 255).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default auto-locator for ticks tries to make 'nice' ranges (like the nearest hundred).

You just need to set the x-limits

```
plt.gca().set_xlim([0, 255])
```

to fix your problem.